# HTTP proxy over ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, http

I can browse the internet by using a SOCKS proxy :

```
ssh -D 1080 myserver
```

I now want to set up a HTTP proxy server, and the server then sends the HTTP package to the SOCKS proxy. If this is possible, how?

I'm doing this with the hope that my iPhone could use my HTTP proxy.

myiPhone --> myComputer.HttpProxy --> MyComputer.SocksProxy --> SSHServer --> someWebSitesBlockedByGFW

Comment: There are three questions here: HTTP, SOCKS, and SSH. You seem utterly confused to me. You don't need both a local HTTP proxy and a local SSH proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Try privoxy.
http://geeklad.com/google-chrome-socks-proxy-workaround

> All I have in my config is:
>   forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:1080 .

Comment: Works like a charm, I also have `listen-address  127.0.0.1:59530` in config to define listening port and then I run with `privoxy --no-daemon ~/.config/privoxy.socks` as my own user.

Comment: The dot at the end is important, goes to the end of the config line!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Tinyproxy](http://banu.com/tinyproxy/), where the proxy is running on the remote host and you have an SSH tunnel to it (see ssh's manpage about ssh -L).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bitvise Tunnelier to SSH to a server. It acts as a socks5 proxy. Polipo can bridge socks5 proxy and HTTP proxy, which means it speaks both sock5 and http language.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "HTTP proxy server, and the server then sends the HTTP package to the SOCKS proxy."

That makes no sense. An HTTP Proxy server would not communicate with a SOCKS Proxy(at least not directly anyway and if it was indirect it'd take a lot of manipulation).

But you can use both an SSH Server(with SSH -L not -D) and an HTTP Proxy.

Or you could use an SSH SOCKS server (-D), but without an HTTP Proxy.

A SOCKS Proxy would be forming a similar function to an HTTP Proxy, but with a different protocol. I can't see how you could use the two together.  Besides the fact that it wouldn't be necessary to.