# Spam Activity From my computer

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, http, spam-prevention

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I'm using HTTP proxy over ssh as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/290201/http-proxy-over-ssh). When I start TinyProxy, I can see the traffic log.

Edited:
If you look at the log, you can see that all of the traffic is advertisements. In addition, although I do not have any application running like firefox, thunderbird, or pidgin etc. there is a huge traffic. So there must be an application running at background.

Do you know any way to detect that application? How can I find the application that cause advertisement traffics?

**ps ax**

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:01 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    7 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/0]
   21 ?        S<     0:00 [cpuset]
   22 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   23 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   24 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
   26 ?        S      0:00 [sync_supers]
   27 ?        S      0:00 [bdi-default]
   28 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
   29 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
   30 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
   31 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
   32 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
   34 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
   35 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
   36 ?        SN     0:00 [ksmd]
   37 ?        SN     0:00 [khugepaged]
   38 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
   39 ?        S      0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
   40 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   48 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
   49 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
   50 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
   51 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
   52 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
   75 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
  240 ?        S<     0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
  241 ?        S<     0:00 [xfslogd]
  242 ?        S<     0:00 [xfsdatad]
  243 ?        S<     0:00 [xfsconvertd]
  245 ?        S      0:00 [xfsbufd/sda3]
  246 ?        S      0:01 [xfsaild/sda3]
  330 ?        S      0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  333 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
  472 ?        S<     0:00 [cfg80211]
  479 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
  671 ?        S      0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
  779 ?        S      0:00 [xfsbufd/sda4]
  781 ?        S      0:01 [xfsaild/sda4]
  785 ?        S<     0:00 [ttm_swap]
  800 ?        S<     0:00 [hd-audio0]
  803 ?        S<     0:00 [hd-audio1]
  857 ?        Sl     0:00 rsyslogd -c5
  869 ?        Ss     0:04 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
  881 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
  883 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
  905 ?        Ssl    0:02 NetworkManager
  906 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
  910 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
  918 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [bunyamin-hp.local]
  919 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  920 ?        S<     0:00 [krfcommd]
  956 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
  980 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
  985 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
 1000 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
 1006 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
 1009 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
 1024 ?        Ss     0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
 1025 ?        Ss     0:00 atd
 1026 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
 1029 ?        Ss     0:01 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
 1034 ?        Ssl    0:00 whoopsie
 1091 ?        Ssl    0:00 lightdm
 1216 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
 1224 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
 1241 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
 1356 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
 1447 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord/colord
 1539 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
 1723 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
 1724 ?        S      0:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
 2077 ?        Z      0:00 [lightdm] <defunct>
 2433 ?        Z      0:00 [lightdm] <defunct>
 3491 ?        S      0:00 [flush-8:0]
 4023 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:14]
 4034 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
 4035 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:3]
 4036 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
 4037 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/1]
 4038 ?        S      0:00 [migration/2]
 4040 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
 4041 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/2]
 4042 ?        S      0:00 [migration/3]
 4043 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:1]
 4044 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
 4045 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/3]
 4047 ?        S      0:00 [irq/43-mei]
 4070 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:0]
 4072 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:0]
 4164 ?        Ss     0:00 anacron -s
 4549 tty7     Ss+    1:13 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 4683 ?        Sl     0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 47
 4718 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 4729 ?        Ssl    0:00 gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
 4765 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
 4768 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
 4769 ?        Ss     0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
 4779 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
 4786 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 4788 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon -f /home/bunyamin/.gvfs
 4797 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
 4799 ?        Sl     0:03 metacity
 4805 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
 4811 ?        Sl     0:10 gnome-panel
 4814 ?        S      0:00 syndaemon -i 2.0 -K -R -t
 4819 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 4821 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
 4826 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
 4828 ?        Sl     0:06 nautilus -n
 4830 ?        Sl     0:02 nm-applet
 4832 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
 4835 ?        Sl     0:00 bluetooth-applet
 4851 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/pulseaudio/pulse/gconf-helper
 4854 ?        Sl     0:04 /usr/lib/indicator-applet/indicator-applet-complete
 4859 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
 4863 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 4865 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 4871 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
 4874 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
 4876 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
 4878 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
 4887 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-printers/indicator-printers-service
 4888 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
 4889 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
 4906 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/geoclue/geoclue-master
 4929 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/ubuntu-geoip/ubuntu-geoip-provider
 4938 ?        Sl     0:11 /usr/lib/gnome-applets/multiload-applet-2
 4939 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-applets/cpufreq-applet
 4953 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
 4955 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
 4957 ?        Sl     3:22 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 4973 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
 4997 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
 5000 ?        Sl     0:00 telepathy-indicator
 5007 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
 5012 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
 5018 ?        Sl     0:00 gnome-screensaver
 5019 ?        Sl     0:01 zeitgeist-datahub
 5025 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 5033 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
 5041 ?        S      0:00 /bin/cat
 5052 ?        Sl     0:08 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c '/home/bunyamin/Desktop/SSH Tunnel'
 5058 ?        S      0:00 gnome-pty-helper
 5067 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
 5090 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
 5130 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
 5135 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh -c nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
 5136 ?        SN     0:00 run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
 5358 pts/4    Ss     0:00 bash
 5482 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
 5487 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/2:0]
 5550 ?        Sl     1:15 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja 4957 true plugin
 5717 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
 5824 ?        SN     0:00 /bin/sh /etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common
 5825 ?        SN     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader
 5872 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
 5888 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
 5889 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
 5909 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /var/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth1.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient-f5f0
 5912 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.
 5975 pts/1    Ss+    0:00 /bin/sh -c '/home/bunyamin/Desktop/SSH Tunnel'
 5976 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/sh /home/bunyamin/Desktop/SSH Tunnel
 5977 pts/1    S+     0:00 ssh -p443 makarna@178.63.21.16 -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000
 5980 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-http --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
 6034 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:0]
 6054 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/2:2]
 6070 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:3]
 6094 ?        Sl     0:02 gedit /home/bunyamin/Desktop/a.html
 6101 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
 6130 pts/4    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

**TinyProxy LOG**

```
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
mx1.u4gf.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=2959021&T=3&_salt=1516586745&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsunshinefelling.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D45%253Aplus-size-dresses%26id%3D7512%253A2012-01-25-22-42-00%26format%3Dpdf%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D101&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    bye
    bye
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    connect to ad.bharatstudent.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
142.91.199.250.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=2913320&_salt=2228719469&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
173.208.94.117 - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3187816&_salt=462045326&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
mx1.a54m.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=2887338&T=3&_salt=2925281520&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsecretskirt.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_contact%26view%3Dcontact%26id%3D1%26Itemid%3D95&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
108.62.75.54.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3218437&T=3&_salt=2939054384&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vifinances.com%2Ffinance-investing%2Finsurance-investment%2Fis-life-insurance-investment-necessarily-the-way-to-go.html&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    bye
173.208.94.22 - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=2922824&T=3&_salt=705371051&B=12&m=2&u=%3A%2F%2Fsunshinefelling.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D44%3Amature-womens-fashion%26id%3D6917%3A2012-01-25-22-37-27%26tmpl%3Dcomponent%26print%3D1%26layout%3Ddefault%26page%3D&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
23.19.10.44.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=160x600&section=3512129&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
142.91.189.27.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3660215&_salt=2921537966&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.scanmedios.com:80
    bye
142.91.217.158.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globaltakeoff.net/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=160x600&section=2077929&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
23.19.76.194.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=3127996&T=3&_salt=1952612979&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oseey.com%2Fpure-core-watch%2Fcarbon-fiber-watch%2Fcarbon-monoxide-poisoning-awareness.html&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
mx1.e6sb.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.scanmedios.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=3522638&T=3&_salt=3444993091&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsunshinefelling.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D6013%3A2012-01-25-22-25-54%26catid%3D40%3Abig-beautiful-women-fashion%26Itemid%3D96&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.tagjunction.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
23.19.76.154.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=2569393 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ads.creafi-online-media.com:80
    bye
108.62.109.115.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3315330&_salt=2385926515&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
142.91.217.214.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=3634166&T=3&_salt=1590442300&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwealthterritory.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_mailto%26tmpl%3Dcomponent%26link%3DaHR0cDovL3dlYWx0aHRlcnJpdG9yeS5jb20vaW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fY29udGVudCZ2aWV3PWFydGljbGUmaWQ9NDY2NDoyMDExLTA3LTA2LTEzLTI2LTUwJmNhdGlkPTQxOnNlcnZpY2VzJkl0ZW1pZ&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
108.62.185.184.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ads.creafi-online-media.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=2885766&T=3&_salt=107120374&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Feconomicccore.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Dcategory%26layout%3Dblog%26id%3D48%26Itemid%3D98%26limitstart%3D45&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    bye
    bye
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    connect to ad.tagjunction.com:80
    bye
108.62.75.252.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=3213387&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    connect to ad.tagjunction.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
173.208.94.29 - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=3006024&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
23.19.31.84.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=2586703&_salt=2905995697&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
oxx-ef-Words.ipwagon.net - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3630499&_salt=4037530564&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
142.91.185.53.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3512541&_salt=1134875077&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
108.177.187.37.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3168350&T=3&_salt=548860046&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehealthyliving.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D34%253Ahealthy-food%26id%3D4681%253A2012-05-16-20-40-19%26tmpl%3Dcomponent%26print%3D1%26layout%3Ddefault%26page%3D%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D53&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    bye
    connect to ads.creafi-online-media.com:80
108.177.223.180.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3331290&T=3&_salt=1270334669&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vegls.com%2Faccident-attorneys-firms%2Fauto-accident-attorney%2Ffind-the-correct-auto-accident-attorney.html&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
142.91.185.38.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=160x600&section=818253 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    bye
    bye
108.62.75.230.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ads.creafi-online-media.com/st?ad_type=pop&ad_size=0x0&section=3323456&banned_pop_types=29&pop_times=1&pop_frequency=86400&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    bye
142.91.217.194.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3068801&T=3&_salt=1246107431&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmoodoffashionandbeauty.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D756%3A2011-07-13-13-13-43%26catid%3D36%3Afashion-clothes%26Itemid%3D55&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.smxchange.com:80
108.62.185.235.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=3307618&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    bye
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
108.177.168.183.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3582877&T=3&_salt=3271923155&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwomenhealthroad.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D5780%3A2011-12-12-16-56-53%26catid%3D40%3Ahealth-issues%26Itemid%3D96&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
23.19.3.100.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=2895969&T=3&_salt=207805714&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Feconomicccore.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D46%253Aeconomic-news%26id%3D6079%253A2011-09-29-07-39-13%26format%3Dpdf%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D96&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
142.91.199.212.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=2956039&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
142.91.189.169.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=3004691&T=3&_salt=2747591679&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.qtsfinancial.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D5406%3Afinancial-statement-english-page%26catid%3D43%3Afinancial-analysis%26Itemid%3D99&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
23.19.31.58.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3323560&_salt=3172064457&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
iei-ix-Words.ipwagon.net - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=3187813&T=3&_salt=1110944041&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.workinhouses.com%2Fhtml%2Fwallingford-ct-connecticuts-best-places-for-your-home.html&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to cookex.amp.yahoo.com:80
173.208.94.116 - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=3213592&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    connect to ads.creafi-online-media.com:80
    bye
108.62.75.99.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=2913321&T=3&_salt=333033369&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffashionstreetlight.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D28850%3A2011-12-20-12-59-39%26catid%3D45%3Afashion-accessories%26Itemid%3D101&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
142.91.217.208.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://cookex.amp.yahoo.com/v2/cexposer/SIG=18kthu27g/*http%3A//ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=2682517&T=3&_salt=1378331643&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.economicwindows.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D40%253Afinancial-info%26id%3D3854%253A2011-07-06-13-25-37%26format%3Dpdf%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D96&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    bye
    bye
108.62.185.228.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3315448&_salt=4241487555&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
108.62.185.220.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ads.creafi-online-media.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=3269968 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.tagjunction.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    bye
142.91.185.47.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/st?ad_type=pop&ad_size=0x0&section=2958317&banned_pop_types=29&pop_times=1&pop_frequency=0&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
108.177.168.183.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=3582877&T=3&_salt=1313872999&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwomenhealthroad.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D5753%3A2011-12-12-16-56-46%26catid%3D40%3Ahealth-issues%26Itemid%3D96&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.tagjunction.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.globe7.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
108.62.75.53.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.tagjunction.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=3127172&T=3&_salt=2152278771&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oslims.com%2Ffashion-coffee%2Ffashion-slimming-coffee%2Fso-whats-your-poison-coffee-or-tea.html&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    bye
108.62.75.170.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=2909210&_salt=1773835502&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
23.19.79.3.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.globe7.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=3571505&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
142.91.217.216.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=3630472&T=3&_salt=462936220&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.economicwindows.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D41%253Afinancial-services%26id%3D4854%253A2011-07-06-13-26-56%26tmpl%3Dcomponent%26print%3D1%26layout%3Ddefault%26page%3D%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D97&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
142.91.189.176.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=3187822&T=3&_salt=325267799&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Feconomysea.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_mailto%26tmpl%3Dcomponent%26link%3DaHR0cDovL2Vjb25vbXlzZWEuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2NvbnRlbnQmdmlldz1hcnRpY2xlJmlkPTYzNDk6MjAxMS0wOS0yOC0yMC0wNC0xOSZjYXRpZD00NzplY29ub21pYy1uZXdzJkl0ZW1pZD05Nw&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.adserverplus.com:80
142.91.190.240.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=2956040&T=3&_salt=3354730349&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdomarketings.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D279%3AWhy-Contractor-Leads-Are-Best-For-Getting-Ideal-Construction-Prospects%26catid%3D2%3Abusiness&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
108.62.75.6.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=3323456&T=3&_salt=1244915826&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdomarketings.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D989%3AThe-Basics-of-Failure-Mode-and-Effective-Analysis%26catid%3D2%3Abusiness&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
142.91.217.220.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=2921135&T=3&_salt=1337464905&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Financezone.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D7236%3A2011-09-05-19-56-54%26catid%3D49%3Acareer-banking%26Itemid%3D99&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
108.62.178.229.rdns.ubiquityservers.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=160x600&section=3168350&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
108.177.168.187.rdns.ubiquity.io - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.smxchange.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=3285387&pop_nofreqcap=1&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" - -
skg-wr-Words.ipwagon.net - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=0x0&y=29&s=3153972&_salt=3512711469&B=12&m=2&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
    bye
    connect to ad.yieldmanager.com:80
mx1.u4gf.com - - [17/Oct/2012 07:38:53] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=160x600&s=2959021&T=3&_salt=1516586745&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsunshinefelling.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Darticle%26catid%3D45%253Aplus-size-dresses%26id%3D7512%253A2012-01-25-22-42-00%26format%3Dpdf%26option%3Dcom_content%26Itemid%3D101&r=1 HTTP/1.0" - -
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited the question to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat -p` (on linux - should list connections and programs on that connection. You can then cross reference that to your logs, or whois information on the hosts to work out which connections there are suspect, and which are the programs causing them.

If its an external connection - for example, if you happened to leave tinyproxy without any form of restrictions on who can access it, netstat won't be that helpful. In which case consider setting the allow and deny blocks on tinyproxy appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

TinyProxy is already telling you the traffic is on port 80, so I'd do this:

> lsof -i tcp:80

which will show all processes using port 80.

Comment: Won't that just point you to TinyProxy, since it is making the to-port-80 connection? As I understand the question, the OP wants to know how to find out what is making the connection *to* TinyProxy in order to track down the actual source of the connection.